# CodeIQで標準入力と標準出力がわかりません

Tags: java

CodeIQ（https://codeiq.jp/）の問題に挑戦しているのですが、ideoneで自動採点される問題の、標準入力と標準出力の書き方がわかりません。
選択言語はJavaです。
例えば、以下のような問題があったとしてどのように書けばいいのでしょうか。

【問題】
標準入力から整数が一行に一つ入力されます。偶数を求めなさい。

【入出力サンプル】
INPUT

```
1
23
456
7891
```

OUTPUT

```
456
```

各プログラミング言語の標準入出力サンプル（https://codeiq.jp/node/1598）も見たのですが、よくわかりませんでした。

宜しくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

やり方は色々ありますのでその内のひとつとして以下に例を示します。
javaで標準入力と言えば、[System.in](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/7/api/java/lang/System.html#in)のことです。
正確には標準入力ストリーム(クラスとしてはInputStream)と言います。
標準出力は[System.out](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/7/api/java/lang/System.html#out)
正確には標準出力ストリーム(クラスとしてはPrintStream)と言います。

ストリームは言わば文字の列・並びのことです。
文字の並びを入力してintとして読み込むには変換する必要がありますが、
こういう場合文字列として読み込んでそれからintに変換したりしますが、
[Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/7/api/java/util/Scanner.html)を使うと文字のストリームから変換や変換可能なデータが残っているかのチェックなどができます。
以下はScannerを使ったintの読込の例

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InputInt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);//標準入力ストリームからScannerのインスタンスを作る

        while(sc.hasNextInt()){//ストリームからintとして読込できるか調べる
            int n = sc.nextInt();//ストリームからintに変換して読み込む
            if(n % 2 == 0){//偶数であるか？
                System.out.println(n);//標準出力ストリームに書き出す
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。ご提示いただいたソースも日本語の説明も大変よくわかりました。
ちなみに while(sc.hasNextInt()) で入力毎に処理するのではなく、全ての入力を見てからOUTPUTすることはできないのでしょうか。例えば「偶数の和を求めなさい」のような問題の時にはどうすれば良いのでしょうか。

Comment: @misa  全ての入力が終了してから処理する場合例えば[ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/7/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)のようなクラスを使ってそれぞれの値を保存しておいて後で処理します。
しかし、【入出力サンプル】のような場合にまとめて処理することが（必ずしも）求められているわけではありません。

Comment: 度々すみません。ArrayListで値を保存しておく方法を試してみたのですが、7891が入力の最終行であることを判断して次の処理に移る方法がわかりませんでした。ご教授いただけないでしょうか。

Comment: @misa  `while-loop`の終わりが入力の終わりです。